# How to reuse a cell that is inside another table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following situation:

- There's a table view controller that displays all font family names, and it's inside a storyboard
- Inside the UITableViewController in the storyboard there's a cell with identifier "FamilyName" that has also a disclosure indicator linked to a segue
- I added a UISearchController that should filter the results of the previous table view controller

Inside the table view controller that acts as results updater I registered the same reuse identifier:

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "FamilyName")
```

And I'm calling dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:, but I get a different UITableViewCell. I'd like to get the same cell that is in the storyboard inside the other table view controller, so that it's already linked to a segue.

Answer (score 1):

Reuse your tableView. Don't make a new one just change the data source.  This should work as intended. Just modify the data source and update the table.

Comment: How should I reuse it? it's inside the storyboard file, I don't know how to instantiate it.

Comment: Just change your data source. If your data is stored in an array, you change the contents of the array and then call [tableview reloadData] to update the table.

Comment: The situation is more complex: one table view controller should display the data, and the other one implements UISearchResultsUpdating and it's inside a UISearchController. I can't simply use the first table view controller's table view, they're two separate table view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "FamilyName")
```

That means: Do *not* use the storyboard to get the cell. So you can hardly be surprised when the cell doesn't come from the storyboard: you said not to. The only way to get a cell from a storyboard is for the table view to register *no* class or nib for this cell reuse identifier.

Comment: If I register no class and I call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: the app crashes.

Comment: Yes, because this table view controller was not instantiated from a table view controller scene in the storyboard.